# correct form of word 'exist

Tags: grammar, usage

Correct one?

1) Nepotism, a practice that has existed as long as mankind permeates our society, from business to politics.

2) Nepotism, a practice that has been existing as long as mankind permeates our society, from business to politics.

Comment: Welcome to the English Language Learners StackExchange. It's helpful for everyone if you can be as specific in your questions as possible. What is it about these two possibilities that you are unsure of, and why? What research have you done to try to solve the problem yourself? Questions just asking people to correct your grammar are too broad, but if there's a specific thing you're uncertain of, or feel that you don't understand the reasons for, then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

"Exist", like most verbs denoting a state, does not usually take the continuous form "be existing".

The iWeb corpus has only 577 instances of "[be] existing" against 415325 of "exists", 667059 of "exist" and 182665 of "existed". (By '[be]', I mean any form of the verb 'be')